# db2 using CASE with AND inside a SUM

Tags: sql, sum, db2, case

I have multiple lines in a select query on db2 that use CASE with AND inside of a sum function. This worked fine on mySQL but no longer works due to the 'AND'.

Am I not able to use that keyword along with a case statement? I'm trying to aggregate these things as one value  a piece and can't find IBM's direct solution to this.

Original query:

```
select  
    sum(case when legtype1 = 2 then 1 else 0 end and answered = 1) as total_inbound
    , sum(case when legtype1 = 2 then 1 else 0 end and answered = 0) as total_missed
    , ROUND(COALESCE(100.00 * sum(case when legtype1 = 2 and answered = 1 then 1 end)/
        sum(case when legtype1 = 2 then 1 end), 100),2) as percent_answered

from table1;
```

I've tried

```
 sum(case when legtype1 = 2 then 1 else 0 end, case when answered = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
```

But that's not correct either. I need to sum based on both conditions being satisfied, is there a different way I should go about this in DB2? I would think there would be a way to alias each condition but I've yet to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think DB/2 is stricter about its conditionals, not letting you `AND` an `int` and a conditional, and treat the result as an argument of `SUM`. Essentially, it's not about `AND` - you should see the same problem if you try summing Booleans, e.g. `SUM(answered = 1)`

You should be able to push `AND` inside the `CASE` expression, like this:

```
select  
    sum(case when legtype1 = 2 and answered = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as total_inbound
,   sum(case when legtype1 = 2 and answered = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as total_missed
,   ROUND(COALESCE(100.00 * sum(case when legtype1 = 2 and answered = 1 then 1 end)/
    sum(case when legtype1 = 2 then 1 end), 100),2) as percent_answered

from table1;
```

Comment: It looks like that got it, thank you! I didn't even think to try that

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, you can sum BOOLEAN values as of Db2 11.1.2.2

```
drop  table table1;
create table table1(legtype1 int, answered int);
insert into table1 values (2,1),(2,1),(null, null),(2,0);
select
    sum(legtype1 = 2 and answered = 1) as total_inbound
,   sum(legtype1 = 2 and answered = 0) as total_missed
from table1;

 TOTAL_INBOUND TOTAL_MISSED
 ------------- ------------
             2            1
```